# On the natural homomorphism $\nu:R\longrightarrow S^{-1}R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1_R$ and $S$ an multiplicatively closed set. We  define the natural homomorphism 
\begin{align*}
\nu:R &\longrightarrow  S^{-1}R, \\
a&\longmapsto \nu(a):=\frac{a}{1_R}.
\end{align*}
where $ S^{-1}R$ is the localization of $R$ on $S$.

In a proposition, I found that $\forall s\in S\subseteq R\implies \nu(s)\in U( S^{-1}R)$, because
$$\nu(s)\cdot \frac{1_R}{s}=\frac{s}{1_R}\cdot \frac{1_R}{s}=\frac{s}{s}=1_{ S^{-1}R} $$
**But should it be $\forall s\in S^*:=S\backslash \{0_R\}$?**

I mean that if we take $s=0_R$, then $\nu(0_R)=\frac{0_R}{1_R}=0_{ S^{-1}R}$. 
 So, it is not unit.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, if $0\in S$, then $S^{-1}R$ is a zero ring where everything trivially is a unit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, $S^{-1}R=\{0_R\} \iff 1_{S^{-1}R}=0_{S^{-1}R} \iff \frac{1_R}{1_R}=\frac{0_R}{1_R} \iff \exists s\in S:\ s(1_R0_R-0_R1_R)=0_R \iff \exists s\in S:\  s=0_R \iff 0_R\in S$.

Comment: @Chris exactly. You might want to accept the answer if it did solve your question.

Comment: Of course. Thank you very much again :)